# npm install on tfs-2017 server failing

Tags: angular, npm, tfs-2017

We are running tfs 2017 on premise.
i have made a build profile for building an angular application
I have added the NPM install and NPM build steps and on both steps i get the error:
`2021-12-28T12:58:51.0183098Z (node:3076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Failed which: Not found npm: null`

I have installed the node package installer on the agent server and i can run npm build command on that server without any problem.  Yet the agents i marked to support npm commands keeps giving this error

any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the cmd command was already working independant of the folder location i was in, which led me to believe the path variable was already working.

But for the agent this did not seem the case... a reboot fixed it.  Long live windows :)

Comment: we met the same issue where command line `npm build` works but the windows agent tells us npm not found null. Adding npm to the path solved it